# La faire profonde en se baissant tout bas

Tags: sens, pronoms-personnels

Je ne comprends pas cette citation de [Pourquoi dit-on "à vos souhaits" lorsque quelqu'un éternue ?](https://lesavaistu.fr/pourquoi-dit-on-a-vos-souhaits-lorsque-quelquun-eternue/). 
"la" est un pronom objet, mais quel est son antécédent ?

2. > Dans son [ouvrage](http://www.revuedlf.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Les-r%C3%A8gles-de-la-biens%C3%A9ance-et-de-la-civilit%C3%A9-chr%C3%A9tiennes-%C3%A0-l%E2%80%99usage-des-%C3%A9coles-chr%C3%A9tiennes.pdf) *Règles de la Bienséance et de la Civilité Chrétiennes*, **Jean-Baptiste de La Salle** écrit ceci :
   >
   > *« Quand quelqu’un éternue, il ne faut pas dire tout haut : Dieu vous bénisse, ou Dieu vous assiste ; on doit seulement, sans proférer aucune parole, se découvrir et faire la révérence – et `la faire profonde en se baissant tout bas` si c’est à l’égard d’une personne à qui on doit beaucoup de respect ».*

Comment: Notice that this is immediately preceded by "faire la révérence," so "la révérence" is a very logical antecedent for "la" in "la faire profonde," especially as the phrase simply develops the idea in the previous one.

Comment: C'est important, le contexte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'antécédent de *la* est *révérence* : faire une profonde révérence.